# How to submit only inputs field that have disapaly: flex

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend, web-frontend

Sorry if I formed the question in a wrong way,
Imagine that I have inputs, some are visible(display:none) and some are not(display:flex).
I can control between them using add ClassList with (display:flex).

The problem: The form is always submitted even though when I have the input fields changed to flex display and they are empty.

What I want to do: I want to check that the form is not submitted unless the active inputs (inputs with flex display) are filled.

HTML:

```
                    <div id="dvd" class="section dvd">
                        <div class="input-wrapper dvd-attribute">
                            <label for="" class="description">Please, Provide Disc Size(MB):</label>
                            <input type="text" required name="size" class="mySize" id="size">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="book" class="section book">
                        <div class="input-wrapper book-attribute">
                            <label for="" class="description">Please, Provide The Book Weight:</label>
                            <input type="text" required name="weight" class="myWeight" id="weight">
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="furniture" class="section furniture">
                        <div class="furniture-attribute">
                            <p class="askDimensions">Please, Provide Dimensions:</p>
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <label for="">Height: </label>
                                    <input type="text" required name="height" class="myHeight" id="height">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <label for="">Width: </label>
                                    <input type="text" required name="width"  class="myWidth"  id="width">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <label for="">Length: </label>
                                    <input type="text" required name="length" class="myLength" id="length">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

SASS:

.section {

```
      align-items: center;
      width: 60%;
      height: 20vh;
      border: solid 2px;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      padding: 0 30px;
      display: none;

      .input-wrapper {
        margin: 0;
      }
    }

    
    .furniture {
      height: unset;
      .askDimensions {
        padding: 20px 0 50px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      .input-wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
      }
    }
    .active {
      display: flex;
    }
```

JS:

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

document.querySelector(".mySwitcher").addEventListener("input", (e) => {

```
let selected = e.target;
if (selected.value.toLowerCase() == "dvd") {
  remove();
  document.getElementById("dvd").classList.add("active");
}
if (selected.value.toLowerCase() == "book") {
  remove();
  document.getElementById("book").classList.add("active");
}
if (selected.value.toLowerCase() == "furniture") {
  remove();
  document.getElementById("furniture").classList.add("active");
}
```

});
});

function remove() {
document.querySelectorAll(".section, .section input").forEach((tag) => {

```
tag.value = " ";
tag.classList.remove("active");
```

});
}

Answer (score 1):

**This is one way to check an input(any element) is displayed as a block or not and then you can perform any specific task according to display property in javascript**

```js
let allInputs = document.querySelector('input')
  allInputs.forEach(input=>{
    console.log(input.style.display);
  })
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question.
I tried this solution but it didn't work. The main problem is with select option tags. When I choose which section I want to add style.display='flex' to it using the select options, the form is submitted even though the fields are empty.

Comment: to loop through select elements as well just change the selector `document.querySelector('input, select')`